# Jar is not able to find log4j configuration file,which is configured using manifest.mf

Tags: java, jar, log4j, executable-jar

I want to read log4j.xml file which is outside the jar inside etc folder. So i created manifest file as follows

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.8.2
Created-By: 1.6.0_24-b07 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)
Built-By: Administrator
Main-Class: com.him.LogPrinter
Class-Path: ./lib/log4j.jar ./etc/log4j.xml
```

My class file is as follows

```
package com.him;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
public class LogPrinter {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(LogPrinter.class);
public static void main(String[] args) {
    logger.debug("I am a debug message");
    logger.info("i am a info message");
    logger.error("i am a error message");
    logger.warn("i am a warn message");
    System.out.println("hello");
}

}
```

when i run my jar file using

```
java -jar myapp.jar
```

it shows usual exception of no appender could be found for logger and no log file generated.

When I put log4.xml file inside jar file it gives the required output.

Please help I am not able to figure out why configuration file is not picked even if it is in classpath configured using manifest.mf file.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Besides that I wouldn't do it like this, you'd need to specify the directory, not the file, just like a regular classpath.

Comment: Thanks @DaveNewton it worked(specifying directory,not the file)

Comment: Moved to answer with alternative solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to specify the directory, not the file; like a normal classpath.

I'm not sure I like this idea, though; I think it would be more convenient to supply a config file path on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Log4J is looking for log4j.xml file into root of the classpath. It means that you should move it one level up from the `etc` folder where it is now and fix your manifest file as well. I believe you actually do not have to mention the log4j.xml in manifest at all. Just pack it into your jar.